# How to create and manage an img file on 256 MB RAM machine?

Tags: memory-limit, imgburn

I completed the installation of Windows XP, MS Office 07, and some minor programs on a machine with 256 MB of RAM.

I want to install all the identical on another three machines.

Because of small amount of RAM, it's not possible to do it with Ghost, Acronis or similar application.

Is there another way to make an img file and to copy it to the next comp (which also has 256 MB of RAM) ?

Comment: Cant you temporarily increase the amount of RAM for this task?

Comment: I have ghosted computers with 256 MB RAM before. (Using ghost 8.3 and a CDROM which booted to DOS.) So it should be possible. Which error do you get when you try to image them?

Comment: Maybe Clonezilla  according to http://clonezilla.org/  it requires 192mb of RAM so try that.

Comment: these computers must be really slow with only 256mb of ram.  RAM is cheap get some more.

Answer (score 0):

http://drbl.sourceforge.net

Take another PC give it more than 512mb and setup drbl server.  You can use the LiveCD or make a dedicated box. Put a 500gb or 1tb hard drive in the server and you can store dozen of different images on it.  A drbl server can be setup or "network boot" alias "pxe boot" alias "pixie booting".

See hardware requirement below.
http://drbl.sourceforge.net/faq/fine-print.php?path=./1_Common/02_hardware_requirement.faq#02_hardware_requirement.faq